# WINAPI Print - Two paper types with same dimensions

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, gdi

I am having with a problem printing using WINAPI. There is this printer, DS40, and this printer provides two different "paper sizes" (6x4", 6x4"x2), which have exactly same dimensions, but each does something little different (reasons behind this are rather difficult to explain, I think it is not necessary to do so here).

For printing, I am using the Qt Framework, which is using the GDI Print API. However, it does not matter which paper variant I choose, it always uses the same one.

When looking into Qt's source code, I found out that it is passing the paper size through this structure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, namely members dmPaperWidth and dmPaperLength.

Now, how can I differentiate between those two paper size variants?

Comment: Try this from your provided link: "dmDefaultSource
Specifies the paper source. To retrieve a list of the available paper sources for a printer, use the DeviceCapabilities function with the DC_BINS flag.
This member can be one of the following values, or it can be a device-specific value greater than or equal to DMBIN_USER."

Comment: The papers do not different by the source. The source is always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in documentation for [DEVMODE structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

`dmPaperWidth`/`dmPaperLength` override `dmPaperSize`

To select a specific `dmPaperSize` (for example A4, Letter, Legal, etc.) use the following settings:

- `dmFields |= DM_PAPERSIZE`
- `dmPaperSize = papersize_index`
- Don't use `DM_PAPERWIDTH` and `DM_PAPERLENGTH` in `dmFields` flag

You can use [DeviceCapabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `DC_PAPERNAMES` to get a list of paper sizes which are supported by current printer.

Comment: I am not sure, but if I understand the documentation right, dmPaperSize is used only for predefined paper sizes, such as A4, Letter, etc. That means I can't set 6x4'' or 6x4''x2 using that.

Comment: Okay, my bad, looks like it is using the dmPaperSize :) Only the Qt sends same values for both the options.